# applying bullet list to dynamically created paragraphs

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to add a bullet list dynamically in word using VBA , list has to be inserted after a bookmark, I create a list of paragraphs using a for loop (data coming from api)  then applying bullet list, logic works , but the bullet list always starts from the second paragraph.

Hrere is code:

```
Set temp3 = ListGalleries(wdNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1)
With temp3.ListLevels(1)
    .Font.Name = "Symbol"
     .Font.Size = 11
    .NumberFormat = ChrW(61623)
   .TrailingCharacter = wdTrailingTab
    .NumberStyle = wdListNumberStyleArabic
    .Alignment = wdListLevelAlignLeft
    .TabPosition = wdUndefined
    .StartAt = 1
End With

Dim oRangeBKM As range
For Each k In entities
        
            If ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Exists("emails") Then    
                Set oRangeBKM = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("emails").range
      

                Set paragraph = oRangeBKM.Paragraphs.Add

                paragraph.range.Style = wdStyleHeading2
                
                paragraph.range.Text = k("entity") & CStr(idx) & vbCr
                
                paragraph.range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplate ListTemplate:=temp3 <<-------- this should work for every paragrpah above? but for some reasons first paragraph created is not part of list
                
            
                
            End If
Next
```

OUTPUT is like:

**email1**

- **email2**
- **email3**
- **email4**
- 

First item does not have any bullet applies & there is an extra empty bullet at last.

Comment: It would be a lot easier if you first defined a list style then applied the list style to the relevant paragraphs.

Comment: @freeflow temp3  is the list style?

Comment: In word you can define a style as a list style. Goto the new style dialog, where it says style type pull down the menu and select list type.  This is different to selecting a numbering/bullet style from the list gallery templates.

Comment: @freeflow - that probably wouldn’t be necessary. I suspect that applying the paragraph style “List Bullet 1” would do the job, perhaps modified to add bold.

Answer (score 0):

To understand why your code doesn't work as you expect run the following

```
Sub scrape()
    Dim para As Paragraph
    Set para = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Add
    para.Range.Text = "Paragraph text" & vbCr
    para.Range.Select
End Sub
```